# Separate each piece of data from sql table through PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I Have a string of data in my SQL table: Renovated, New, Downtown. I would like to display each piece of data into a list through PHP is this possible?

Here is what I have right now:

```
 <details>
  <summary>Listing Features</summary>
 <ul>
  <li><?php echo $page['tags']; ?></li>
 </ul>
</details>
```

Right now all the data is displayed on one 'li' and not individually. Thanks,

Comment: See the `explode()` or `preg_split()` functions.

Comment: Have you tried split string into array using `explode` and loop through array using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tags in `$page['tags']` is delineated by commas, you should split the string by the separator first, then loop over the items rendering a tag per iteration.

```
<details>
  <summary>Listing Features</summary>
 <ul>
  <?php foreach(explode(",", $page['tags']) as $tag) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $tag; ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
 </ul>
</details>
```

Comment: typo, your explode closing brace is not in the correct place. It should be after `$page['tags']`  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string that contains comma separated values, you could use explode

```
$values=explode(',',$str);
```

And then loop through this array, and echo a list item for each

```
foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<li>$v</li>"
}
```